# Three exceptions for int

Tags: java, exception

I am trying to create a code where an int is supposed to be entered and then have exceptions for if the int is not between 9 and 99, another exception if a double is entered instead of int and then a third exception if a string is entered. How do i do this? i have below what i have so far but am not sure how to correct it. thanks

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    boolean correct = true;
    do {
        try {
            System.out.println("Enter an Integer between 9 and 99");
            int number = input.nextInt();
            if (number >= 9 && number <= 99) {
                System.out.println("Thank you, Initialization completed");
                correct = false;
            } else if (number < 9 || number > 99) {
                throw new Exception("Integer is not within the range");
            }
            if (input.hasNextDouble()) {
                throw new Exception("Integer not entered");
            } else {
                correct = false;
            }
            if (input.hasNext("")) {
                throw new NumberFormatException("Integer not entered");
            } else {
                correct = false;
            }
        } // check for range
        catch (Exception e1) {
            System.out.println("Number is not within 9 and 99");
            System.out.println();
            input.nextLine();
        } catch (Exception e2) {
            System.out.println("An integer was not entered");
            System.out.println();
            input.nextLine();
        } catch (NumberFormatException e3) {
            System.out.println("An integer was not entered");
            System.out.println();
            input.nextLine();
        }
    } while (correct);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Method *.getMessage()* returns the string given in constructor:

```
throw new Exception("HERE");
```

When you catch Exception, you catch also NumberFormatException, InputMismatchException, etc.
so you must catch broader ones last.

```
catch (NumberFormatException e3) { // Precisier goes first
    System.out.println("An integer was not entered");
    System.out.println();
    input.nextLine();
}
catch (Exception e1) {
    System.out.println(e1.getMessage());
    System.out.println();
    input.nextLine();
}
```